# add parameter to javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, parameters, vimeo

I need to add a color parameter to this javascript (full script [here](http://new.stevenspiel.com/wp-content/themes/Photum/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6))

Color should be dd4c23

```
        vimeo : {
            matcher : /(?:vimeo(?:pro)?.com)\/(?:[^\d]+)?(\d+)(?:.*)/,
            params  : {
                autoplay      : 1,
                hd            : 1,
                show_title    : 1,
                show_byline   : 1,
                show_portrait : 0,
                fullscreen    : 1
            },
            type : 'iframe',
            url  : '//player.vimeo.com/video/$1'
        },
```

Right now the output link is

```
http://player.vimeo.com/video/65191942?autoplay=1&hd=1&show_title=1&show_byline=1&show_portrait=0&fullscreen=1
```

and all it needs is a `&color=dd4c23` at the end to make it work.

It would be global, so I don't mind adding the color to the javascript.

([link to website](http://new.stevenspiel.com/compositions))

Comment: Try to add `color: 'dd4c23'` after `fullscreen`

Comment: that is the answer I provided below already.

Comment: Ummmmm.... `params : { color: "dd4c23", ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
vimeo : {
    matcher : /(?:vimeo(?:pro)?.com)\/(?:[^\d]+)?(\d+)(?:.*)/,
    params  : {
        autoplay      : 1,
        hd            : 1,
        show_title    : 1,
        show_byline   : 1,
        show_portrait : 0,
        fullscreen    : 1,
        color:        : 'dd4c23'
    },
    type : 'iframe',
    url  : '//player.vimeo.com/video/$1'
},
```

Comment: You rock, man. I thought I had tried that, and I got an error. Anyway, works now. thank you!

Comment: yeah, i tried. i have to wait 10 minutes though. I'll do it then. you were just so fast....